# Embedded image doesn't show up in email body

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) to send email with embedded images, but the images doesn't show up in message body in some email client app (eg thunderbird).
I'm suspecting this happened because of `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is set to `quoted-printable`. So it add 3D characters (which is encoding for **=** character) in `src` property of `img` element:

```
<img src=3D"cid:61767c3c-7f99-4f0f-a15b-b5edc0f0c2c4@emailaddress.com">
```

How to turn off `quoted-printable` encoding permanently in nodemailer ? I've tried to set `textEncoding: 'base64'` in message options, but it seems nodemailer ignore it.

```
let message = {
  from: {
    name: 'Someone',
    address: 'someone@emailaddress.com'
  },
  to: {
    name: sender,
    address: emailTo.toLowerCase()
  },
  subject: 'Purchased Tickets',
  html: 'Some text<br><img src="cid:61767c3c-7f99-4f0f-a15b-b5edc0f0c2c4@emailaddress.com"/><br>Some more text<br><img src="cid:1a419f12-1205-49e5-b0f7-fd407c0bfa27@emailaddress.com"/><br>',
  attachments: ticketList.map((t, i) => ({
    filename: `ticket${i + 1}.png`,
    content: t.qrCode,
    cid: `${t.ticketNumber}@emailaddress.com`
  })),
  encoding: 'base64',
  textEncoding: 'base64'
}

transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(info)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in some of my emails, but it does not appear to be related to Content-Transfert-Encoding.
Indeed, the images are displayed on some of my mails with

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

but not all...

Comment: I have tried it with some email client apps, and apparently some displays it and some don't.